# Decorator and decorated classes are in different bean archives

Tags: decorator, cdi, jboss7.x, ear, jboss-weld

My ear application which runs on JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final consists of two jars:

- `lib/one.jar`
- `lib/two.jar`

Both jars are CDI bean archives.

The `two.jar` depends on `one.jar`.

The class beeing decorated is in `one.jar`.

The decorator class is in `two.jar`

If the decorators are declared in `beans.xml` of `two.jar`, they are not enabled.
Does this work as expected?

Since the `one.jar` is developed independent of the `two.jar` and has no dependency to the `two.jar`, I expect the declaration (enabling) of the decorators is in the archive where the decorator classes are stored.

How is it possible to enable a decorator class without to change the archive with classes beeing decorated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the spec, yes this is expected behaviour. CDI 1.1 is hoping to make this easier or at least clear it up a little. For any interceptor, decorator, or alternative you want to use, it must be enabled (beans.xml) in the archive you wish to use it.